# Calling POST as URL ASP.NET web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know how to test POST by typing in the url.
Here's my route Config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "myWebApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/mywebapi/{action}/{ID}/{DeptID}",
                 defaults: new { Controller = "mywebapi", ID = @"\d+", DeptID = @"\d+" }
             );
```

programmatically this is how I call POST
I have 3 text boxes and a button. When user clicks on the button the below program gets called

```
function parseform(button) {
            var id = $("#ID").val();
            var deptid = $("#DeptID").val();
            var name = $("#Name").val();

            var inputdata = {
                id: id,
                deptid: deptid,
                name: name
            }

            if (button.attr('value') === "POST") {
                postdata(inputdata);
            } else {
                console.log("ERROR");
            }

        }
 function postdata(inputdata) {
            $("#response").text("Posted");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "api/mywebapi/Post/",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(inputdata),
                xhrFields: {
                   withCredentials: true
                },
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                   $("#response").text(status+" - "+data)
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

                    $("#response").text(status)

                }
            });
        }
```

In the controller

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public void Post([FromBody]mywebapi value)
        {
        saves to database
        }
```

Here's what I tested

```
http://localhost:222/api/mywebapi/Post/new newwebapi ({"id":"1","deptid":"2","name":"testing"})
```

I get error. How to test this?

thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a POST request, you can't test it in your browser by typing in an address (those are GET requests, which contain no body).

To test these types of things you can use something like [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/)
or [Rest Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en) (if you're using chrome), there's tons of these types of things in whatever your browsers extension store is called.

Some tools you can use are something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

this will let you see what the requests and responses look like, and you can change/modify them as well, though it's probably a bit harder to use than something like PostMan or Rest Console (also more powerful)

Comment: For completeness - there are also console tools around, like `curl` or `wget`

Comment: Can I call a Post from Get function??